# Redirect second language frontpage /da/ to first language frontpage (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

In my Wordpress site I try to redirect the second language frontpage /da/ to first language frontpage BUT NOT the whole subdirectory.

In .htaccess I tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /da/ https://becopenhagen.dk/
```

which redirects the whole language (subdirectory), and this

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /da/index.php https://becopenhagen.dk/
```

which don't redirect anything.

Would this not be possible without plugins or advanced php? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` like this :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /da/$ https://becopenhagen.dk/
```

Comment: Works like a breeze! Thanks for a quick and working solution!